# How to ignore text case while comparing two strings in C++?

Tags: c++, string, compare, alphabetical

I am a beginner coder. I am trying to create a program which will compare two strings **alphabetically**. But It will ignore the *text case*. I am facing problem on it. How can I ignore the text case in **C++**?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string a, b;

    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;

    if ( a > b) {
        cout << "1";
    }
    else if ( a < b) {
        cout << "-1";
    }
    else if (a == b) {
        cout << "0";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert both strings to lower case before the comparison via [`std::tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower):

```
for (auto& c : a) c = std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));
for (auto& c : b) c = std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));
```

Comment: const &  won't work

Answer (score 0):

Use a **case-insensitive** comparison function, such as C's `strcmpi()`, or Windows's `CompareStringA()` with the `NORM_IGNORECASE` flag, or Posix's `strcasecmp()`, etc

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend using a loop and converting both strings to lowercase or lowercase by using `std::toupper` or `std::tolower`

```
for(const auto& i:a)x=std::tolower(x);
for(const auto& i:a)x=std::tolower(x);
```